# On using php mongo execute command showing an error "exception: can't have . in field names", and error code : 16722

Tags: javascript, php, mongodb, execute

I am trying to run a set of java script and update command using by php mongo execute command:

```
$pSsId                      = '123456789';
$pUid                       = 14;
$pRowID                     = '6fce077519d838bb8ed401448dae6e3a';
$pKey                       = 'name';
$pValue                     = 'King Kobra';
$response                   = $db()->execute("
        function(pSsid, pUid, pRowid, pKey, pValue){
            udocs    = db.VizSpreadsheet.findOne({'_id' : pSsid, 'data.uid' : pUid  }).data; 
            posU     = udocs.map(function(d) { return d.uid; }).indexOf(pUid);
            posR     = udocs[posU].rows.map(function(r) { return r.row_id; }).indexOf(pRowid);

            var setCriteria = {};
            setCriteria['_id'] = pSsid;
            setCriteria['data.uid'] = pUid;

            var setObject = {};
            setObject['data.'+posU+'.'+'rows'+'.'+posR+'.'+pKey] = pValue;

            db.VizSpreadsheet.update(
                {
                    setCriteria
                },
                {
                    '$set': setObject
                }
            );
        }", array($pSsId, $pUid, $pRowID, $pKey, $pValue));
```

But the result is error

```
Array ( [errmsg] => exception: can't have . in field names [data.1.rows.0.2#12#07337187ee7e48f92ed1689b22d7ed77] at src/mongo/shell/collection.js:155 [code] => 16722 [ok] => 0 )
```

The collection will look like this

```
"_id" : "123456789",
"data" : [ 
    {
        "uid" : 12,
        "rows" : [ 
            {
                "row_id" : "8979afefedb42aa8c62e9baa83e35ba0",
                "updated_by" : "12",
                "updated_at" : "1428644989",
                "name" : "AAAAAAAAAAA"
            }, 
            {
                "row_id" : "7415f767c62a84173d1dcf82ad1d809d",
                "updated_by" : "12",
                "updated_at" : "1428644989",
                "name" : "BBBBBBBBBBBBB" 
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "uid" : 14,
        "rows" : [ 
            {
                "row_id" : "21b1120811cfe893486e9e9afbebb660",
                "updated_by" : "12",
                "updated_at" : 1428644989,
                "name" : "CCCCCCCCCC"
            }, 
            {
                "row_id" : "6fce077519d838bb8ed401448dae6e3a",
                "updated_by" : "12",
                "updated_at" : 1428644841,
                "names" : "DDDDDDDDDDD"
            }
        ]
    }
```

What i am trying is to update "name" field of second element in "rows" array for "uid" = 14. The data is updated by '$set' method and specifying the element position which is find by javascript code.

The same code executed successfully in shell. 
But in php it fails to detect the position operator.

Answer (score 0):

As an error message says, you cannot use `.` (dots) within your data.
Try separate your 'subfields' with `:` for example:

`setObject['data:'+posU+':'+'rows'+':'+posR+':'+pKey] = pValue;`